# Could not find the program 'konsole'

Tags: kali-linux, kde, kde-plasma-5, konsole, kde-plasma-workspace

Hi i installed Kali Linux 2020.2, went into the plasma, then I start the program, writes that `Could not find the program 'konsole'`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue switching xfce to kde desktop.
Seems to be a known issue and fix not ready yet.

I got a workaround:

1. cd /usr/share/kali-menu
2. Backup application desktops: `sudo cp -r applications applications.bak`
3. Backup exec-in-shell: `sudo cp exec-in-shell exec-in-shell.bak`
4. Change "Terminal=true": `sudo sed -i -e s/Terminal=true/Terminal=false/g applications/*.desktop`
5. Change content in exec-in-shell to following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
konsole --hold -e "bash" "-c" "$1"
```

6. Update actual desktop entries: sudo ./update-kali-menu

I'm not quite sure if this works fine for all desktop entries but works for me by now.